# Retornar un objeto desde una función finalizada para reutilizarse

Tags: python, poo, funciones

Gente, ahora tengo el siguiente detalle.
En mi código tengo una estructura más o menos así:

```
class Jugador:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def metodo_loco(self):
        pass

def cantidad_jugadores(cantidad=0):
    jugador1 = Jugador()
    pass

def juego():
    jugador1.metodo_loco()
```

El linter arroja que no hay variable definida como "jugador 1" en la función juego(). Entiendo que si quiero que las funciones se comuniquen con el exterior debo hacer que retornen valores y así, pero cuando he querido implementar un return justo después de aquí:

```
jugador1 = Jugador()
```

siento que no funciona, porque luego intento acceder al objeto desde la función juego() estableciendo algo tipo:

```
jugador1 = cantidad_jugadores()
```

y se quita el aviso del linter pero VSCode ya no me hace referencia a las variables como objetos cuando coloco el mouse sobre ellos dentro de la función juego(). Tengo rato investigando y, según leí, es porque al finalizar la ejecución de la función cantidad_jugadores(), el recolector de basura se carga al objeto instanciado. Si eso es así, ¿cómo puedo prevenirlo?

Aclaro que el código **es un ejemplo**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las tres posibilidades más imples que tienes para resolver este problema son:

### Retornar una lista, tupla, generador o cualquier otro iterable

@ordago en su respuesta ya lo explica perfectamente, solo añadir que puedes usar listas por compresión:

```
def cantidad_jugadores(cantidad=1):
    return [Jugador() for _ in range(cantidad)]
```

y luego desde la otra función:

```
jugadores = cantidad_jugadores(3)
jugador1 = jugadores[0]
```

...

o desempaquetando:

```
jugador1, jugador2, jugador3 = cantidad_jugadores(3)
```

o puedes retornar un generador o hacer que la propia función sea un generador:

```
def cantidad_jugadores(cantidad=1):
    return (Jugador() for _ in range(cantidad))
```

---

```
def cantidad_jugadores(cantidad=1):
    for _ in range(cantidad):
        yield Jugador()
```

---

```
jugador1, jugador2, jugador3 = cantidad_jugadores(3)
jugadores = list(cantidad_jugadores(3))
```

### Pasar a la función una lista para que la llene o la procese

```
def agregar_jugadores(cantidad=1):
    for _ in range(cantidad):
        lista_jugadores.append(Jugador())

def juego():
    jugadores = []
    agregar_jugadores(jugadores, 2)  # agrega dos jugadores
    # ....
    agregar_jugadores(jugadores, 3)  # agrega otros tres jugadores a los que había
```

Cuando un método/función modifica in place un objeto es siempre buena práctica que el nombre lo refleje, por eso he cambiado el nombre de la función por `agregar_...`, además es buena idea documentarlo claramente ya que la función tiene efectos colaterales fuera de su ámbito (en este caso modifica la lista pasada).

### Usar también una clase para representar tu juego

En este caso, basta con hacer que `jugadores` sea un atributo de instancia y, por tanto, será perfectamente accesible por cualquier método de instancia de la clase.

```
class Jugador:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def metodo_loco(self):
        pass


class Juego:
    def __init__(self):
        self.jugadores = []

    def agregar_jugadores(self, cantidad=1):
        for _ in range(cantidad):
            self.jugadores.append(Jugador())

    def jugar(self):
        for jugador in self.jugadores:
            jugador.metodo_loco()


juego = Juego()
juego.agregar_jugadores(3)
juego.jugar()
```

---

Una cuarta opción sería usar variables globales, pero no aportan nada que no podamos hacer mediante los métodos anteriores y son consideradas generalmente  mala práctica.

Una variable definida dentro de una función en Python es local a la función por defecto en Python. Ésto implica que no puede ser accedida desde fuera del espacio de nombres de la función y que deja de existir tan pronto como la función retorna. Ésto es lo que causa el error mencionado en la pregunta.

Una función puede acceder a una variable global (definida a nivel de módulo) y acceder al objeto asociada a la misma sin problemas. Como en nuestro caso es una lista, que es mutable, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
lista_jugadores = []  # Variable global

def agregar_jugadores(cantidad=1):
    for _ in range(cantidad):
        lista_jugadores.append(Jugador())

def juego():
    agregar_jugadores(2)
    for jugador in lista_jugadores:
        jugador.metodo_loco()
```

En este caso la lista es un objeto mutable y no tenemos que resignar a la variable un nuevo objeto, solo agregamos items al mismo. Pero en el momento que se intenta reasignar un nuevo objeto a la variable, se crea una variable loca con el mismo nombre que solapa a la global dentro de la función, dejando intacta la variable global. Si la lista la definimos dentro de `agregar_jugadores` la variable será local y cuando retorne variable y lista dejaran de existir.

Se puede especificar dentro de una función que una variable no sea tratada como local sino que se considere global mediante el uso de `global nombre_variable`. Al hace ésto, la resignación desde dentro de la función se hace sobre la variable global y no se crea una local. Si la variable no existe se crea en el espacio de nombres global.

Por tanto, podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
def crear_jugadores(cantidad=1):
    global lista_jugadores
    lista_jugadores = []
    for _ in range(cantidad):
        lista_jugadores.append(Jugador())

def juego():
    crear_jugadores(2)
    for jugador in lista_jugadores:
        jugador.metodo_loco()
```

La primera opción es aceptable, ésta en mi opinión debe evitarse a toda costa, para empezar por legibilidad del código.

Hay varias razones por las que el uso de variables globales debe limitarse en lo posible, en mi opinión solo para constantes o en algunos casos muy específicos en las que son variables de estado del módulo o en módulos que actúan como archivos de configuración para compartir estado entre variso módulos.

- Violan la definición  de una función pura, mismo resultado para los mismos argumentos de entrada siempre.
- Causan efectos colaterales fuera de la función, lo que hace el código mucho menos legible y mucho más difícil de mantener y depurar. Y facilitando el conocido como spaghetti code.
- Hacen el código mucho menos reutilizable.

Si bien en un ejemplo simple como éste su uso no acarrea ningún peligro considerable, en proyectos de envergadura pueden ser con frecuencia fuentes de problemas, se llega un momento en el que no es fácil saber desde que partes del código se accede a la variable y cuando y cómo se modifica, lo cual no es trivial ya que modificar la variable afecta a todo el código que la usa. Además de la perdida de legibilidad y de dificultar el mantenimiento, pueden causar bugs que cuestan a veces mucho depurar. En Python se limita un poco todo ésto porque por decisión de diseño las variables no son globales al proceso, solo son globales en el ámbito del módulo dónde son definidas.

Casi siempre hay formas de evitarlas sin tener por ello que perder eficiencia. No siempre son malas, existen casos dónde son perfectamente válidas si se usan correctamente. El caso de las constantes es el más claro, sin ir más lejos el módulo `math` de la stdlib define unas cuantas como tales `pi`, `e`, `nan`, `inf`.

Comment: Gracias por añadir tu respuesta, por lo menos a mi me ha servido para aprender un par de cosas nuevas.

Comment: ¿Y cómo va eso de las variables locales en este caso? Saludos.

Comment: Hola @CarlosReyes ¿A qué te refieres con "cómo va eso de las variables locales "?¿O querías decir cómo sería usando a variables globales?

Comment: Eso. ¿Cómo soluciono el problema usando variables globales? ¿Y por qué se considera mala práctica?

Comment: @CarlosReyes he editado la pregunta, al final intento explicar todo de forma un poco general, espero que aclare algo. Aclaro que lo de buena o mala práctica puede ser hasta cierto punto subjetivo, por mucho que pueda ser una opinión generalizada. También depende de cada caso concreto obviamente.

Answer (score 4):

En el código que has pegado, es normal que te falle porque `jugador1` no es accesible desde el ámbito de la función `juego()`. Si lo que quieres es crear el objeto en otra función, tendrás que devolverlo usando return, y acceder como estabas intentando hacer:

```
def cantidad_jugadores(cantidad=0):
    jugador1 = Jugador()
    return jugador1

def juego():
    jugador1 = cantidad_jugadores()
    jugador1.metodo_loco()
```

El que no te funcione en VSCode el resaltado no es un problema del lenguaje ni de tu código, sino un problema de ese programa.

Tampoco tiene nada que ver con el recolector de basura.

EDIT: Si lo que quieres es devolver varios jugadores como tuplas lo puedes hacer así:

```
def cantidad_jugadores(cantidad=0):
    jugador1 = Jugador()
    jugador2 = Jugador()
    return jugador1, jugador2

def juego():
    jugador1, jugador2 = cantidad_jugadores()
    jugador1.metodo_loco()
    jugador2.metodo_loco()
```

Aunque sospecho que lo que vas a querer hacer es que devuelva un número variable de jugadores, por lo que más que una tupla te recomiendo que devuelvas una lista. Sería algo así:

```
def cantidad_jugadores(cantidad=1):
    lista = []
    for i in range(cantidad):
        lista.append(Jugador())
    return lista


def juego():
    jugadores = cantidad_jugadores(2)
    for jugador in jugadores:
        jugador.metodo_loco()
```

La tupla es útil si sabes que quieres devolver dos o más valores pero sabes siempre cuántos van a ser. Si no sabes cuantos van a ser, es recomendable usar una lista.

Comment: Vale, ¿y si quisiera devolver varios objetos desde cantidad_jugadores()? Porque sé que la sentencia return devuelve una tupla si se quieren retornar varias cosas, entonces me confunde un poco.

Comment: @CarlosReyes he editado la respuesta añadiendo cómo devolverlo en forma de tupla